# How to map JSON to C# Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am having issues with understanding how to make this happen.

Basically we have an API, the user sends a JSON of the format:

```json
{
  "Profile":[
    {
      "Name":"Joe",
      "Last":"Doe",
      "Client":{
        "ClientId":"1",
        "Product":"Apple",
        "Message":"Peter likes apples"
      },
      "Date":"2012-02-14"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a class called `Profile` with parameters `Name`, `Last`, and an object as one of its members called `Client` as well as property `Date`.

Something like this:

```cs
public class Profile {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Last {get; set;}
    public Client client {get; set;}
    public DateTime dDate {get; set;}
}
```

So basically, I am not sure how to grab the JSON and then map it to my object.

Any help with "helping" me understand would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize your json string as (with some modifications to your classes)

```
var yourObject =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonstring);


public class Root
{
    public Profile[] Profile;
}

public class Profile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int ClientId;
    public string Product;
    public string Message;
}
```

Comment: Cool, whats the role of the Root class?, sorry if a newbie question :)

Comment: Since your `Profile` array is inside of an object(json's root object doesn't have a name like xml). I named it `Root`, you can choose any name you want

Comment: @Malice Link is as I intended... I rolled back your update

Answer (score 7):

You can use a JSON library for this, for example [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) which is free. It will map json to your types automatically.

Sample:

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer s = new JsonSerializer();
        return s.Deserialize<T>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)));
    }
```

There is also a NuGet package available.

Comment: Just FYI you can also add it as a Nuget package directly in VS, which is very comfortable

Comment: Not if the field names do not match

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I know is to use JSON.Net by newtonsoft.
To make it easier to understand, I always make matching classes in C# with the same name. 
Then its easier to deserialize it.
As an example, if it is an array of objects in js, it will map to a list of object with the same names in C#.
As for the date time, its a bit tricky. 
Id do the client side validation and Datetime.tryParse in the serverside, itll take care of the dashes or slashes.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<abc> abcList = serializer.Deserialize<List<abc>>(PassedInJsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a long time question, but I would like to add one more option, which **does not use third party libraries, and only uses stock .Net libraries**, and is available from .Net Core 3.1 onwards.

First of all, I leave a link to the official Microsoft documentation (where you will find examples on how to serialize and deserialize json strings): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Let's build on your example. We have our starting json string:

```
{
   "Profile":[
      {
         "Name":"Joe",
         "Last":"Doe",
         "Client":{
            "ClientId":"1",
            "Product":"Apple",
            "Message":"Peter likes apples"
         },
         "Date":"2012-02-14"
      }
   ]
}
```

If we build a data structure that can hold that definition, it would be something like:

```
public class Root
{
  public List<Profile> Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Last { get; set; }
  public Client Client { get; set; }
  public string Date { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
  public string ClientId { get; set; }
  public string Product { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Now, and finally **the answer to how to deserialize a json string into a particular object** without third party libraries:

```
Root root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
```

Where `json` is the variable that contains your json string.

I add another link of interest, the official documentation of the `Deserialize(...)` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize

Something that is really useful is the exception that can be thrown, `JsonException`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonexception

Answer (score 0):

[DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) does the job, but it uses more sophisticated format for DateTime serialization.