# Read JSON file and map to C# objects

Tags: c#, json

I want to read a JSON file and map it to class objects. How would I do that in C#?

### JSON

```
{  
   "companyName":"Test company",
   "companyNumber":"1234",
   "address":{  
      "buildingNumber":"33",
      "street":"Caledon Road",
      "county":"Barking and Dagenham",
      "postalTown":"Essex",
      "postcode":"E62HE"
   }
}
```

### C# Code

```
public class CompanyInfo
{ 
    public string companyName{ get;set;}
    public string companyNumber{ get;set;}
    public string buildingNumber{ get;set;}
    public string street{ get;set;}
    public string county{ get;set;}
    public string postalTown{ get;set;}
    public string postCode{ get;set;}
}
```

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988395/how-to-map-json-to-c-sharp-objects

Comment: Though I am late to comment, but with good answers it hurts if none is accepted. Answer by Timothey Harvey did worked for me besides tool that he recommended.

Answer (score 6):

Make your code

```
    var json = {  
                 "companyName":"Test company",
                 "companyNumber":"1234",
                 "address":{  
                     "buildingNumber":"33",
                     "street":"Caledon Road",
                     "county":"Barking and Dagenham",
                     "postalTown":"Essex",
                     "postcode":"E62HE"
                  }
               }

 public class CompanyInfo
    { 
    public string companyName{ get;set;}
    public string companyNumber{ get;set;}
    public Address address {get;set;}
    }

 public class Address
   {
    public string buildingNumber{ get;set;}
    public string street{ get;set;}
    public string county{ get;set;}
    public string postalTown{ get;set;}
    public string postCode{ get;set;}
   }
```

then use `Newtonsoft.Json` to Deserialize the json

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompanyInfo>(json);
```

Comment: buildingNumber should be inside the Address

Answer (score 5):

First create a class to match the JSON, this can be easily done using this super-handy tool [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)

the JSON you provided converts to this

```
public class Address
    {
        public string buildingNumber { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string county { get; set; }
        public string postalTown { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        public string companyNumber { get; set; }
        public Address address { get; set; }
    }
```

Then deserialize your JSON into an object of the type you just defined using JSON.net (nuget Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json)

```
public void LoadJson()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        RootObject company = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
   }
}
```

I suggest renaming RootObject to something more meaningful in your application

Comment: Thanks for the json2csharp.com suggestion!

Comment: Seconded. Years later, solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You need two classes - `CompanyInfo` and `Address`. `CompanyInfo` must contain `Address` object, because json have address object in companyInfo:

```
public class CompanyInfo
{ 
    public string companyName{ get;set;}
    public string companyNumber{ get;set;}
    public Address address{get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public string buildingNumber{ get;set;}
    public string street{ get;set;}
    public string county{ get;set;}
    public string postalTown{ get;set;}
    public string postCode{ get;set;}
}
```

Then you should deserialize json using `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet Package or something other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSON.Net [enter link description here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

This article can be interesting too: [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)