# Trying to Deserialize Json to Object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON, but all properties of my object come null.

My JSON:

```
{"List":{"item":[{"id":"47861","nome":"2,4-D AMINA 840 SL","codMapa":"5002","fabricante":"ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA","embalagem":"BALDE","tipoEmbalagem":"AÇO","volume":"20.0000","unidade":"LITROS"},{"id":"47863","nome":"2,4-D AMINA 840 SL","codMapa":"5002","fabricante":"ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA","embalagem":"BOMBONA","tipoEmbalagem":"PLASTICO","volume":"5.0000","unidade":"LITROS"},{"id":"47865","nome":"2,4-D AMINA 840 SL","codMapa":"5002","fabricante":"ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA","embalagem":"BOMBONA","tipoEmbalagem":"PLASTICO","volume":"10.0000","unidade":"LITROS"},{"id":"47867","nome":"2,4-D AMINA 840 SL","codMapa":"5002","fabricante":"ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA","embalagem":"BOMBONA","tipoEmbalagem":"PLASTICO","volume":"20.0000","unidade":"LITROS"},{"id":"47869","nome":"2,4-D AMINA 840 SL","codMapa":"5002","fabricante":"ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA","embalagem":"CAIXA","tipoEmbalagem":"PAPELÃO","volume":"20.0000","unidade":"LITROS"},{"id":"47871","nome":"2,4-D AMINA 840 SL","codMapa":"5002","fabricante":"ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA","embalagem":"FRASCO","tipoEmbalagem":"PLASTICO","volume":"1.0000","unidade":"LITROS"},{"id":"47873","nome":"2,4-D AMINA 840 SL","codMapa":"5002","fabricante":"ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA","embalagem":"TAMBOR","tipoEmbalagem":"AÇO","volume":"200.0000","unidade":"LITROS"}]}}
```

My class:

```
    public class ListaProdutosAutorizados
    {
        public List<ProdutoAutorizado> ProdutosAutorizados { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProdutoAutorizado
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public int? codMapa { get; set; }
        public string fabricante { get; set; }
        public string embalagem { get; set; }
        public string tipoEmbalagem { get; set; }
        public decimal? volume { get; set; }
        public string unidade { get; set; }
    }
```

And my Code:

```
var lResposta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListaProdutosAutorizados>(stringJson, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Comment: C# classes of yours do not match with the JSON Structure... user http://json2csharp.com/ to generate C# classes for your JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON shoud look like this to match your C# classes:

```
[
  {
    "id": 47861,
    "nome": "2,4-D AMINA 840 SL",
    "codMapa": 5002,
    "fabricante": "ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA",
    "embalagem": "BALDE",
    "tipoEmbalagem": "AÇO",
    "volume": 20.0000,
    "unidade": "LITROS"
  },
  {
    "id": 47863,
    "nome": "2,4-D AMINA 840 SL",
    "codMapa": 5002,
    "fabricante": "ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA",
    "embalagem": "BOMBONA",
    "tipoEmbalagem": "PLASTICO",
    "volume": 5.0000,
    "unidade": "LITROS"
  },
  {
    "id": 47865,
    "nome": "2,4-D AMINA 840 SL",
    "codMapa": 5002,
    "fabricante": "ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA",
    "embalagem": "BOMBONA",
    "tipoEmbalagem": "PLASTICO",
    "volume": 10.0000,
    "unidade": "LITROS"
  },
  {
    "id": 47867,
    "nome": "2,4-D AMINA 840 SL",
    "codMapa": 5002,
    "fabricante": "ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA",
    "embalagem": "BOMBONA",
    "tipoEmbalagem": "PLASTICO",
    "volume": 20.0000,
    "unidade": "LITROS"
  },
  {
    "id": 47869,
    "nome": "2,4-D AMINA 840 SL",
    "codMapa": 5002,
    "fabricante": "ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA",
    "embalagem": "CAIXA",
    "tipoEmbalagem": "PAPELÃO",
    "volume": 20.0000,
    "unidade": "LITROS"
  },
  {
    "id": 47871,
    "nome": "2,4-D AMINA 840 SL",
    "codMapa": 5002,
    "fabricante": "ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA",
    "embalagem": "FRASCO",
    "tipoEmbalagem": "PLASTICO",
    "volume": 1.0000,
    "unidade": "LITROS"
  },
  {
    "id": 47873,
    "nome": "2,4-D AMINA 840 SL",
    "codMapa": 5002,
    "fabricante": "ALBAUGH AGRO BRASIL LTDA",
    "embalagem": "TAMBOR",
    "tipoEmbalagem": "AÇO",
    "volume": 200.0000,
    "unidade": "LITROS"
  }
]
```

Note that your `id`, `codMapa` and `volume` properties can get unserialized wrongly as their type in your original JSON is string and not decimal or int.

If you deserialize this new JSON into a `List<ProdutoAutorizado>` it should work.

Comment: Nice point Corentin, and for Daniel, that's always good take a look into de docs > 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need same property names on the json file. In your example you have `List` then there must be a property in the C# class called `List` and same thing for the `item` as well.

The other way to match them is using `JsonProperty` attribute.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988395/how-to-map-json-to-c-sharp-objects) for more info.