# Pass response data from RestSharp to JSON Properties

Tags: c#, json, api, restsharp

I am new to API, RestSharp and JSON. I got the Response Data from the API, my problem is I didn't know how to pass the response data to JSON Properties that I've been readied.

Here is my Code.

This is the API response I received.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "link_4txtnKwrBbTTQfRwswSLcinw",
    "type": "link",
    "attributes": {
      "amount": 65656,
      "archived": false,
      "currency": "USD",
      "description": "2323",
      "livemode": false,
      "fee": 0,
      "remarks": "12321",
      "status": "unpaid",
      "tax_amount": null,
      "taxes": [],
      "checkout_url": "https://pm.link/------",
      "reference_number": "sadXlwd",
      "created_at": 1670820915,
      "updated_at": 1670820915,
      "payments": []
    }
  }
}
```

RestSharp Code:

```
private void GenerateLink(double amount, string description, string remarks)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.paymongo.com/v1/links");
    var request = new RestRequest("", Method.Post);
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic c2tfdGVzdF9aMXdma2tUaDdaUUNjR25oNnlOYUpQZks6c2tfdGVzdF9aMXdma2tUaDdaUUNjR25oNnlOYUpQZks=");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"data\":{\"attributes\":{\"amount\":" + amount + ",\"description\":\"" + description + "\",\"remarks\":\"" + remarks + "\"}}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);

    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
                
    }
}

private void BtnPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    amount = 20000;
    description = "JC DIAZ";
    remarks = "Delivery Date : " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");

    GenerateLink(amount, description, remarks);
}
```

The variables that I want to fill with RestSharp Response Contents

```
public partial class Attributes
{
   [JsonProperty("amount")]
   public int Amount = 0;

   [JsonProperty("archived")]
   public bool Archived = false;

   [JsonProperty("currency")]
   public string Currency = "";

   [JsonProperty("description")]
   public string Description = "";

   [JsonProperty("livemode")]
   public bool Livemode = false;

   [JsonProperty("fee")]
   public int Fee = 0;

   [JsonProperty("remarks")]
   public string Remarks = "";

   [JsonProperty("status")]
   public string Status = "";

   [JsonProperty("tax_amount")]
   public object TaxAmount = "";

   [JsonProperty("taxes")]
   public List<object> Taxes = null;

   [JsonProperty("checkout_url")]
   public string CheckoutUrl = "";

   [JsonProperty("reference_number")]
   public string ReferenceNumber = "";

   [JsonProperty("created_at")]
   public int CreatedAt = 0;

   [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
   public int UpdatedAt = 0;

   [JsonProperty("payments")]
   public List<object> Payments = null;
}

public partial class Data
{
   [JsonProperty("id")]
   public string Id = "";

   [JsonProperty("type")]
   public string Type = "";

   [JsonProperty("attributes")]
   public Attributes Attributes = null;
}

public partial class Model
{
   [JsonProperty("data")]
   public Data Data = null;
}
```

I tried this code, but it still returns no results.

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Attributes>(response.Content);
string value = model.CheckoutUrl;
```

I expect to populate the attributes class with the contents of RestResponse.

Comment: If you neeed some help you will have to replace the images by  the text.Newer use images in your post except when it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: `"checkout_url"` is totally different from `model.CheckoutUrl`  in this simple context.  How are you mapping the `.Content` to an object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map JSON to C# Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988395/how-to-map-json-to-c-sharp-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to create a root class and use it to deserialize your json

```
Model model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(response.Content);

string value = model.Data.Attributes.CheckoutUrl;


     public partial class Model
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("attributes")]
        public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
    }
```

or if you only need attributes data, you can do it without the extra classes

```
Attributes attributes = JObject.Parse(response.Content)["Data"]["Attributes"].ToObject<Attributes>();

string checkoutUrl = attributes.CheckoutUrl;
```